# Firebase hosting not going live - stuck on "Continue setup to direct traffic to your domain"

Tags: web-hosting, dns, godaddy, cname

I'm stuck on the last stage("going live") of **Firebase hosting**. 
[image]

I have a Godaddy domain:
[image]

As u can see i put down all the CNAME and A records.
[image]
[image]

I'm adding my firebase.json in case it's conneted in some manner.
[image]

So,
**what I'm doing wrong?

How can I make it work?**

Notice that the site works..
But i believe something is wrong, otherwise firebase would finish the process.

tnx

Comment: Have you asked them?

Comment: As indicated previously, we don't do individual website troubleshooting here (please refer to [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):  `we would close questions such as "What am I doing wrong here?"`). You'll need to ask for help from the [Firebase product community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk).

Comment: i add a full example on a specific website so people could understand, it happens in all my projects .

Comment: I am also using Firebase hosting, do you notice that SSL (https) in your website. that is only available when you finish the process. Continue setup option I also see in my console, but don't worry about that, it is helpful when you done some changes in DNS setting.

Comment: I disagree. I have a SSL connection on my website and it seems like the process haven't finished yet. are u sure? @Goyllo

Comment: Firebase process 1. Create a project name 2. You will get a subdomain from firebase like example.firebaseapp.com 3. To set custom domain first you need to add txt records, which you have done 4. Then you need to add CNAME so you can open your site through your domain name, which is also done, otherwise your domain will not going to open 5. Next they will add your site on their SSL certificate(Yes, your SSL is used by all firebase user who is using custom domain). So I think the process is complete, but the button continue setup is still there, so I think it will disappear after sometime.

Comment: Or, you can contact them for [technical support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/). You will get 5 free support per year. I have contact them recently and they provide support very fast through email.